# CSS/jQuery: Reduce the height of overflow'ed div as another div slides in

Tags: jquery, css, overflow

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vZjnd/

Given the facts

.wrapper height is fixed.

.main is overflow-auto.

.slide content is variable so height is variable from time to time.

my goal is

.main to be pushed up (height reduced) as .slide occupies part of .wrapper

Any idea?

Comment: your html is bad designed from the first place.

Comment: It's just a dummy. Feel free to modify @Royi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
$('#up').click(function() {
    $('.slide').slideUp(function() {
        $('.main').height($('.main').height() + $('.slide').height() + 'px');
    });
});

$('#down').click(function() {
    $('.slide').slideDown(function() {       
        $('.main').height($('.main').height() - $('.slide').height() + 'px');
    });
});
```

code: http://jsfiddle.net/vZjnd/5/

You can use `animate` to make it more smoothly.

Comment: Great soloution. Just remember to disable the button you press, so you can't slideUp if its already up - since it will keep adding/removing the heght for each press. Else do a height check :)

Comment: Thanks Samich, can we make it run parallel with slideUp/Down?

Comment: Slight bug when repeatedly clicking the same button, but +1 anyway.

Comment: Guys, I just wanted to show where OP should looking for a solution :). So, sorry for bugs in code ;)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think of to accomplish this is by doing the following:
Add a new rule to the onclick, $('.main').animate({'height': '-=15px'}, 500); or use += when sliding it away? but this does mean that the scrollbar will disappear during the animation.

Comment: How do we get 15px to be deducted as .slide's height is variable?